# Omit "+10" green notification in global inbox for my old&good answers which already gained my attention enough times

Tags: feature-request, reputation, up-votes, achievements-dialog

It is pleasant to see that my question or answer is useful for somebody. My revisit&improve attempt of them is sometimes triggered by this notification.

But when the question or answer is popular, seeing "You have gained yet another +10 for this answer" is less interesting and useful. It looks a bit annoying.

How can I receive fewer notifications about upvotes for answers that already sent enough such notifications? For example, such notifications may be grouped together and eye-catching green "+N" may be shown only when there are 100-rep-points worth of such notifications, i.e. "You gained cumulatively 100 additional rep points for your 6 old and good answers".

Comment: Easier to just delete the answer since it's already served its purpose

Comment: @random, No. A sluggish upvote stream shows that the anser (or question) is still needed. Also I don't like deletion in general and often see "404 for moderation" both on SE and on other sites. Deletion is poorly compatible with my curiosity about "what is that heated meta discussion about?"

Comment: Solution: place a +500 bounty. You won't see the light for at least 50 upvotes.

Comment: I expect that in this case all such notifications will be ommitted, not just for old answers.

Comment: I guess you wanna omit the -5 notifs for this proposal.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493, I don't know why this proposal is so unpopular. Maybe downvoters are confusing this with "not notify on upvotes on old questions whatsoever"?

Comment: I think it's just because people like green boxes with +reps. Like me.

Answer (score 4):

The `+10` is to show you the appreciation you get from your fellow users. Since that is a major part in 'rewarding' users that contribute, it is very important (and a nice feeling hopefully) to see the light flashing green.

Of course, the rep cap will kick in at some point, and they will prevent you to see any more upvotes, so you won't be bothered any more.

Comment: Rep cap per day. If you manage to trickle upvotes, it will keep appearing

Comment: @random: Indeed. They won't bother Jon at least.

Comment: Is seeing this 60 times for one anser still expected to provide apperciation feeling?

Comment: @Vi.: It does work for me :)